# The boolean modifier changes some part of the face orientation of the design

Tags: modifiers, faces

I've browsed the internet in a search for this problem but I haven't find anything that could explain how to fix it.
I am trying to create a stamp to print in 3d to emboss. I've created my design, prepared it all so it doesn't have too many vertices etc.
My support is a simple square I have extruded a bit to fit the shape more closely.
Now, before applying anything, all the faces are facing on the right direction, after applying the boolean, only some part show as red and don't apply the boolean.
It's a single shape so I have no idea how to change that. If anyone has a clue, I would gladly have it!

Thank you very much!

Edit: separated objects screenshot and file added here [image]

[image: design to emboss][image: blue is how it supposed to behave, red is the none affected parts][image: before boolean modifier]

Comment: That image is too small for us to see what's going on, but you could try going into Edit mode, Selecting All, and then using Shift-N to recalculate the normals. If that doesn't help, please add another image created via Blender's Window > Save Screenshot menu which will display full screen here.

Comment: @JohnEason : ah, was a screenshot 2772x1336px image did the post resize it?(I edited the post with the screen from blender). I tried shift n and recalculate, but I can't do that without applying the boolean first otherwise, that is how it shows in edit mode (editing my first post with the images)

Comment: That's better! Are you actually trying to cut out the pattern or join the two together? If you're trying to join them, why not just select both and Ctrl-J them? If you're cutting, try selecting 'Fast' on the modifier. That sometimes helps.

Comment: @john Eason: I am trying to cut it out (to make an emboss stamp if that makes sense?)

Comment: If none of Leo's suggestions in his answer work we'll need to see your Blend file. You can share it here: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the help! So I tried both solution, found no non-manifolds or issues (I think I did it right, I followed a few tutorials) and I did prepare both surface with the remesh but it didn't change anything. I am adding a screen of the separate design as well and will share my file in the link @john Eason suggested.

Comment: I guess that your cutter is simply too complicated for the modifier to handle correctly. In fact applying it and hiding the cutter shows that the object has been cut ok, but a lot of the detail is simply composed of faces on end  with no thickness which wouldn't 3D print anyway.

Comment: I worked around and found a way. Remade my vector in illustrator so the part that I want "out" are not filled anymore, made it a solid, added a shape behind so the piece would have a support when printed and it worked. I don't know why I was trying to make such a complicated process. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Glad you're sorted!

Answer (score 0):

Before the boolean operation check that the different geometries have correct normals and are manifold. Use the 3D Print tool add-on to find non-manifolds or fix issues before any boolean operation. Also before the boolean modifier experiment with the remesh modifier for the two different meshes. Having more geometry on a mesh can help the boolean modifier execute better. If you do use the remesh modifier before the boolean modifier be prepared for heavy and slow computations. Make a backup copy of the geometry before using the remesh boolean combo. Lastly use the 3D Print add-on to solve mesh problems after you apply the boolean operation.